2 flex containers inside a flexbox, equal height issue
I have 3 card in a row. Each card has 2 sections and contains dynamic texts.
It looks like this:


.card {
  display: flex: flex-direction:column;
  flex: 1
}

.card__wrapper {
  display: flex: flex-direction:column;
}

.bundle-top {
  flex: 1;
}

.data {
  flex: 1;
}
<div class="card ">
  <div class="card__wrapper">
    <div class="bundle-top">
      <span class="bundle-title">Lorem ipsum</span>
      <p class="bundle-description">
        Lorem ipsum
      </p>
      <span class="price">
                    <span class="price-value">299</span>
      </span>
      <div class="cta__wrapper">
        <a class="button tiny button__tertiary" href="/">
          <span>Start Trial</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="data">
      <ul>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum
        </li>
        <li>
          Lorem ipsum
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I would like to have the same height of all cards (as the highest) but I would also like .bundle-top to have the same height on all cards, it sholud take the height of the highest as well. I would like this for .data element too.
I would like it to look like this:

I use flex, and have added flex:1 to the elements that I would like to have the same height but it dosnt work. The only thing thats working is that all cards have the same height.
This is the css that I have so far:
Actually I have tried a lot of different things but I dont have that css any more

Could you provide us with your used CSS too? mininmal reproducible code

Yes sure, I can update my question with it



You have a typo in your CSS after a property needs to be an ; not :. E.g. display: flex; flex-direction: column;


This is still not enough code to reproduce the problems that are appearing for you. You want three cards the same height but just providing us with one. And it seems like you are yousing bootstrap so might as well ad bootstrap as a tag too.



It seems you want to have the same height, but have you considered the small screens renderings ? if the answer is you want the same height event if they are one on top of another, maybe some fixed height would suit you better, if you always want them side by side, a table would do the trick, and if you want responsive with heights reajusting when they are in column, then i don't see another way that javascript.

@MrJoky yes there was a typo in the css here that I wrote but not in my real code. I didnt provide code for all three cards because they all look the same. The only thing that differs is the content inside. Some cards can have more text that others since its dynamic. No I dont use bootstrap

@Neil on mobile we have a slider to view the cards horizontally. I dont want to use a table tough. you cant use a flexbox for this?
